# making http and https request to different site from client browser in react js

Tags: reactjs, https

How can I make a request over an http/https website in react js from client browser? I want to test few different site connectivity from client browser and generate a report.
I tried with fetch and axios libraries but it does not work to ignore ssl error e.g. to use `rejectUnauthorized` option. Also, it has very limited error catching options e.g. `ERR_NETWORK` with axios and `fetch failed` for fetch.
I see another approach is to import node https module in react app using config-overried.js but not sure how to do that. Any suggestions?